# to check weather a user defined number is a perfect cube in PHP or cube of an integer

Tags: php

I need to find whether the given number is cube of an integer.

*Question asked in college:* Design a PHP page to check if entered number is a cube of an integer in PHP.
In the program below, `is_float()` is not working to check whether the `$num2` is float or not. I don't know why.

```
<?php
$num=$_POST["t1"];
$num2=pow($num,1/3);
echo $num2."<br>";
$res=$num%$num2;
echo $res."<br><br>";
$test=is_float($num2);
echo "float ".$test."<br>";
var_dump(is_float($num2));

//if($num%$num2==0 || $num%$num2==1)
if (is_float($num2)==TRUE) {
  echo"<font color='FF0000' size='+2'>". $num. " is not Cube of an integer</font>";
} else {
  echo "<font color='FF0000' size='+2'>". $num. " is  a Cube of an integer</font>";
}
?>
```

Comment: So what do you expect?What does it mean is not working

Comment: even if the value is like 1,25,36,...etc the float value is always true but it should be false right !!

Comment: You are checking `$num2=pow($num,1/3);` for number 25 you get 2.92401773821.Of course is going to be a float,maybe you meant to check for `$num` not `$num2`?

Comment: but when u put this number i.e 2.92401773821($num2) in is_float() it result true and for non float number like 25($num) in pow() same result i.e true why ??

Answer (score 0):

I hope your teacher isn't on *Stack Overflow* ;)

I'm only going to give you some advises, so you can find out the answer by yourself. Come on, it's not that difficult!
Anyway, I posted the solution too.

Have you tried to check which type of number is returning:

```
pow(27, 1/3);
```

My guess is PHP will always return a float when you'll ask him to calculate a number with a power less than 1, else an integer.

**Solution:** The best here would be to check if the result of pow() is equal to the entire part of itself. You can do that with the floor() function (See http://php.net/manual/function.floor.php) :

```
// ...
$num2 = pow($num, 1/3);
$test = ($num2 == floor($num2))
// ...
```

Comment: i didn't get it let $num=27 then $num2=3 and $test=10  when value is 64 then $num2=4 and $test=10 but it not constant now when value is 125 then $num2=5 and $test=1 , when value is 9 then $num2=2.0800838230519 and $test=1 so how can i use the $test value to determine whether the value is cube or not   guide me !!